# Uncrowding a scatter plot when most points lie near lower end of X-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2011

Given an Excel scatter plot thus:

[image]

where the bulk of the points lie at the lower end of the X-axis, how can the lower end be made to look less crowded (without removing data points), while maintaining the overall shape of the plot? I've tried a logarithmic scale, and does that uncrowd it somewhat, but I was wondering if there was another approach?

Excek for Mac 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that will make a difference is to remove outliers. If you filter the data to exclude even the top 3 X values, the X axis will span only half the range and the data points in the lower X values will be spread out more.

Create a separate chart for the top 3 X values, format the X axis to a suitable minimum value near the 8000 mark and place the two charts side by side.